# Как в GridLayout установить размер textview?

Tags: android, grid-layout

Есть GridLayout, в котором несклько textView, один textView с картинкой, картинка растягивается на всю клетку, а нужно установить конкретнй размер, что проблематично. Как мне сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте значение `Padding` для `textView`

```
android:padding="4dp"
```

Comment: не помогает, пробовал еще margin, он уменьшает, но увеличивает внешний разрыв